# How to open task or event in a new tab [Lightning version]

Tags: javascript, lightning

Is there a way to open a task or event in a new tab? I am on Lightning version, and the link for any task or event is "javascript:void(0)" - so if you try to open in a new tab it just comes up blank. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will soon be available in the upcoming  Winter17 version. It will be released this weekend.